# How to create / integrate database on TYPO3

Tags: mysql, typo3

Good Morning, 
as from the title, i'd like to create a proprietary database to be integrate in a Typo3 website.

I'd like to receive some advise on **which is the best solution**: 
- is it  possible to create tables directly from Typo3?
- is it better creating a database, for example with MySQL and then integrate 
  it?

In the second case, how coud that be done?

are there other options?

I hope this is not an already answered topic, in case, please send me to it ( i could not find so much information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the DBMS of your existing database? Do you need to access those tables/schemas from TYPO3?

Comment: I see you're a new user.  I know nothing about typo3, so I can't help there, however instead of hoping that this isn't an old topic, do a couple of searches and report your results.  For example, "I searched for '[mysql] [typo3] import database' but the only result wasn't helpful."  This lets everyone know you've expended some effort to solve the problem yourself, which will improve the quality of answers you get.

Comment: thanks to both of you.
i did some researches  " i could not find so much information", sorry if i didn't explain in a proper way. 
I searched for "create DB for typo3" , " how to integrate DB in typo3" etc..


@Oliver i have to decide wheter to create a new DB from scratch using for example MySQL or to use Typo3 tools if there are any to create database directly.. There is an already webpage which  now needs a DB for example a table that records person with particular authorizatios and normal person.

Comment: What do you mean with "integrate database into TYPO3"? Is it maybe a scenario where you only want to display the foreign database through the TYPO3 system, but still want to be able to write via custom clients into the foreign database ("mixed scenario")? Or do you want to be able to read and write only with TYPO3 into this database (a "TYPO3 only scenario")? In the latter case you should follow the advices of Urs.

Comment: exatly, i'm trying to understand which is, in my case, the best solution, if develop a foreign database or directly creating it in TYPO3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add a custom Extension to TYPO3, containing custom tables. From a content side, this is perceived as a "database", right?

TYPO3 has a framework for that called Extbase. You can "kickstart" a TYPO3 extension with the "Extension Builder" https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder by entering the "Model" (the data structure) via GUI and then you get all tables etc. automatically set up.

After that (aside from general TYPO3 knowledge), there is some coding involved. In theory, it's possible to make a "round trip" back to the extension builder from the code, but I've never done that.

You need to know / learn the specificities of extbase / php, which is is based on some "convention over configuration" rules and has some additional tweaks to plain PHP (functional comments). Here's a great resource: http://www.extbase-book.org/.

With that, you have great flexibility and powerful tooling to build almost anything inside TYPO3.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the answer.
URs i think you got the point, i'm going to see those links! 


What if instead of using "kickstart" i'd like to connect an existing database?

I'm trying to figure the best solution out:
I have to create a database aiming to handle the accesses in a building and other stuff. The project and those table, should be upgradeable

Answer (score 0):

From a TYPO3 view it is best if you are able to hold your data in the TYPO3 database. You need to create an extension to handle your data. In TYPO3 an extension can define it's own tables and with updates of the extension updates in the datastructure are handled automatically.

Since version 8 there is a new layer (doctrine) and so it is possible to define further databases for individual tables. With some restrictions you are able to even use different database (-systems) for different tables.

Anyway you could program your own database interface to get and store your data independent from any TYPO3 restrictions, but then you need to handle everything on your own.

Using the TYPO3 core API will help you in multiple ways to handle your data without programming everything anew.
Especially if you use extbase (and the EXT:extensionbuilder) you will get a complete BE data handling, FE-Plugins with Fluid templates to present your data, even data management from the FE could be generated for you just by defining the datastructure. Of course versioning, workspace and timed visibility support are also available if you use TYPO3 structures which includes some (mostly invisible) fields aside from `uid, hidden, deleted`.